# Prefix not found! For PAN:4111110000000211

Tags: php, api, magento, payment-gateway

I am integrating "FCMBwebpay" payment gateway api with php magento. I have integrated it with form and added required parameters. Now when i click on "Pay" button, parameters send to the FCMBwebpay site. Then after selecting "Visa/Mesterio" card and adding test card number

- Card no: 4111110000000211
- cvv: 123
- Exp. date: 05/17

When I submit it, then it's redirect to blank page and getting error

> Prefix not found! For PAN:4111110000000211"

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Please help me to solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Magneto has a fixed list of BIN numbers that it knows about.  That list is a production list that does not contain manufacturer and issuer test numbers.

Your test number will NOT be validated by Magneto because it has no knowledge of it.

I don't know a great deal about Magneto, but I would take a guess that if you dig into the documentation for it, there will be a way of adding that BIN prefix into the system so that it does recognize it, and allow you to test things correctly.

Comment: Thanks Shawty. There is nothing about BIN number into this payment gateway. I am getting this error when i add VISA card number and CVV number and EXP date. So can you please check it. I am adding screenshot of error with this post.  Please check it. and help me out this.       [CHECK IMAGE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2IoNs.png)

Comment: If your using a 3rd party gateway, there's nothing I can do to help.  Do you actually have access to the underlying codebase?  If you dont, then you need to contact whoever runs "validcardnigeria.com" and ask them to add the bin prefix to their systems so that you are able to test it, if you DO have access to the underlying code base, then the answer to your question will be in the documentation.